# Upload file with AWS S3 signed url always setting content-type binary/octet-stream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url, signed-url

I am facing a problem where the content-type always changes during the upload process. I am using lambda and nodejs to generate a URL. Here is my code. I would be grateful for any help! [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the file type of the file in your request object?

Comment: "video/mp4" of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code for generating the Signed URL works ok. The problem seems to be with the actual uploading of the file. Try these options and let's see if you get a better result:

1. In postman use the binary option and not the form-data[image]

   form-data adds a lot of additional values
2. Create a nodejs file and test with this code

   ```
   const axios = require('axios');
   const fs = require('fs');

   (async () => {
       const file = fs.readFileSync('./download.mp4');

       await axios.put(signedUrl, {
           data: file,
       }, {
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
           }
       });

   })();
   ```

   The result I get:
   [image]